# How to get FULL URL in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I want to get the **full URL**, not just the `Path`, not just the `Query`, and not `RouteValues`.

The entire URL as it has come in the raw form.

How can I do that in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`UriHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper?view=aspnetcore-6.0) extension methods `GetDisplayUrl()` or `GetEncodedUrl()` to get the full URL from the request.

> **GetDisplayUrl()**
>
> Returns the combined components of the
> request URL in a fully un-escaped form (except for the QueryString)
> suitable only for display. This format should not be used in HTTP
> headers or other HTTP operations.

> **GetEncodedUrl()**
>
> Returns the combined components of the
> request URL in a fully escaped form suitable for use in HTTP headers
> and other HTTP operations.

Usage:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions;
...
string url = HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl();
// or
string url = HttpContext.Request.GetEncodedUrl();
```

Comment: Working on **.Net 6**, get the **full URL** within Razor Page cshtml

`<meta property="og:url" content="@(ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.GetDisplayUrl())">`

Comment: doesn't work or even exist

Comment: @Cloud not sure what you mean, it definitely exists - check the linked docs. This Q&A applies to Razor pages

Comment: No, it does not anymore

Answer (score 10):

You can do it by this way. In `.net core`

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
@{
    string url = Context.Request.Path;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Core is always a bit different. Appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use `HttpContext.Request.Scheme + HttpContext.Request.Host` to get `https://localhost:xxxx`,then use `HttpContext.Request.Path + HttpContext.Request.QueryString` to get path and query:

```
var request = HttpContext.Request;
var _baseURL = $"{request.Scheme}://{request.Host}";
var fullUrl = _baseURL+HttpContext.Request.Path + HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
```

Comment: For some reason I was skeptical that the `Host` property included the port number, but Yiyi is spot on, it does indeed include the port.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`PageLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.pagelink?view=aspnetcore-6.0) method of `IUrlHelper` to get the absolute URL to a page.

In the page handler (or controller), `IUrlHelper` can be accessed via the `Url` property:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    string url = Url.PageLink("/PageName", "PageHandler", routeValues);
    ...
}
```

If you want to generate a URL to a controller action, use [`ActionLink`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.actionlink?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

*Works in ASP.NET Core 3.0 and above.*

Answer (score 0):

You could create an extension class to use the `IHttpContextAccessor` interface to get the `HttpContext`. Once you have the context, then you can get the `HttpRequest` instance from `HttpContext.Request` and use its properties `Scheme`, `Host`, `Protocol` etc. as in:

```
string scheme = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
```

For example, you could require your class to be configured with an `HttpContextAccessor`:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{        
  private static IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor;
  public static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
  {           
      HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;  
  }

  public static string AbsoluteAction(
      this IUrlHelper url,
      string actionName, 
      string controllerName, 
      object routeValues = null)
  {
      string scheme = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Scheme;
      return url.Action(actionName, controllerName, routeValues, scheme);
  }
  ....
}
```

Which is something you can do in your `Startup` class (*Startup.cs* file):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    ...

    var httpContextAccessor = 
        app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
        UrlHelperExtensions.Configure(httpContextAccessor);

    ...
}
```

You could probably come up with different ways of getting the `IHttpContextAccessor` in your extension class, but if you want to keep your methods as extension methods in the end you will need to inject the `IHttpContextAccessor` into your static class. (Otherwise, you will need the `IHttpContext` as an argument on each call).